# Facebook share description is not shown when on my wall

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

I am using this code to share user achievements on my app

```
    if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(), 
        FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {

        // Publish the post using the Share Dialog
        try {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
            .setApplicationName(getString(R.string.fb_app_name))
            .setName(parameters.getString("name"))
            .setCaption(parameters.getString("caption"))
            .setDescription(parameters.getString("description"))
            .setLink(parameters.getString("link"))
            .setPicture(parameters.getString("picture"))
            .build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

when I am setting the "link" to my app Google Play link after share only content of Google Play link shown on my wall (It looks like I shared the app link), but if I am also want to see "caption" and "description".

How to share a story from my app with some story + link of my app?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I think, that we haven't got the opportunities to solve this. Official Facebook docs says:

'If your app share contains a link to any app on Google Play or the App Store, the description and image included in the share will be ignored. Instead, we will scrape the store directly for that app's title and image (and if there is no image, the share won't include one).'

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the reason is some google restriction it does not allows to share a google play link and provide your own description etc.
The solution for this might be put the link from google play in share massage.